# Mapeamento EF de entidade associativa com Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, fluent-api

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer um mapeamento sem utilizar `ICollection`, ou pode até ser usando, mas não gostaria que o banco criasse uma classe, só para poder ligar as duas classes.

```
class Pessoa
{
   public Guid IdPessoa { get; set; }
   public string Nome { get; set; }
}

class Telefone
{
   public Guid IdTelefone { get; set; }   
   public string Numero { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<Pessoa> PessoasList { get; set; }
}
```

No mapeamento o sistema criaria no banco a entidade `Pessoa`, a entidade `Telefone` e criaria uma entidade `PessoaTelefone` só com os Id's, e eu gostaria que fosse criado apenas as entidades `Pessoa` e `Telefone` com um `IdPessoa` na como `foreign key` na entidade `Telefone`. Quero que o EF crie a classe sem essa entidade fraca.

Existe como fazer, ou eu tenho que mapear na unha informando o id no telefone e no momento da persistência recuperar o id gravado e persistir a outra entidade?

Comment: Tem como fazer sim, mas queria entender o motivo de você não fazer questão de usar a entidade associativa, que é justamente o correto.

Comment: O Morrison disse que há como, mas na minha concepção não há como fazer um relacionamento N>N sem uma associação. E se for possível, como disse o Morrisson e não tenho base para discutir com ele, parece um tanto "gambi", pois as associações foram projetadas exatamente para esse fim e querer retirar isso, vai de encontro a todas as regras de BD, como, integridade e etc. É possível como disse o colega, mas eu não iria por esse caminho nunca, a menos que algo extremamente novo, funcional e lógico viesse a existir. Associação ainda é, para mim, o melhor caminho para isso.

Comment: Então @CiganoMorrisonMendez,  eu to imaginando em questão de performance, e até mesmo de ter que lembrar de uma tabela de associação que é criada automaticamente pelo EF, acho que o BD acaba inchado levando em consideração a quantidade de dados que pode vir se eu pedir todos os dados da minha entidade junto com uma segunda entidade, teria um custo enorme tendo que fazer join entre duas tabelas + 1 auxiliar, que eu vejo como incorreta ja que na classe que terá N para 1 só precisa apenas do ID desse 1

Comment: @Leo Não procede isso que você falou. O caso da entidade associativa por Fluent API é uma criação automática mínima, isso justamente pro caso de você precisar apenas associar chaves primárias. Do ponto de vista de desempenho, criar uma tabela associativa (que é o recomendado) ou usar essa entidade mínima tem performance idêntica. A tabela associativa ainda tem as vantagens de ter campos extras para agregar ainda mais informações na associação. Se quiser, posso responder, mas não vou usar essa abordagem Fluent API e explicar o porquê.

Comment: @Leo, você tem uma relação A) onde uma pessoa pode ter vários telefones, mas um telefone só pode estar para uma pessoa. B) Ou uma pessoa tem vários telefones e um telefone pode estar para várias pessoas. C) Ou uma pessoa só pode ter um telefone, mas um telefone pode estar para várias pessoas?

Comment: @PabloVargas, o telefone foi apenas um exemplo, mas imagine o seguinte, eu tenho na relação cliente/ dados, algo do tipo ClienteTelefone, ClienteEndereco, ClientePedido, ClienteFollwoUp, enfim posso ter N amarrações á Entidade Cliente, e fiquei me perguntando se essas amarrações onde teria apenas o Id de cada lado, me causa algumas pergunas:

1- Tda vez que eu persistir um novo tel tenho que gravar a entidade Cliente, junto com os dados da entidade tel ja existente?
2- Se for persistir só o novo telefone como é feita a persistência nessa entidade fraca, já que a mesma não é mapeada no ORM ?